# Get any kind of validation error from WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I'd like to get any validation error from my input controls.

So far i have several viewmodels that all implements a `ValidationViewModel` which implements a `ViewModelBase` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. 
The `ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Look at [this link](https://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/) where I got the validation idea from. His and my validation models are basically the same, but mine is split into two.

Any property change will, as designed, fire the propertychanged event, which the `ValidationViewModel` listens for and does all the custom validations. This is all nice and good.

The problem here is that validation only happens if a property changes... But according to this, excellent, [article](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) the binding engine executes validation rules and tries to do a type conversion before the property is set, which will not make my validation fire.

Imagine a Textbox bound to an integer where the user has entered 'a' as an example. Then i'm left with a red border. How can I catch any kind of validation error on this control? Both custom and default.

My goal is to have a save button which is disabled on any kind of error in my view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have separated views from viewmodels. The type conversion binding error is purely on view side.

You can use `Validation.Error` attached routed event to catch any binding errors, but you must set NotifyOnValidationError in the Binding set to true

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error(v=vs.110).aspx

When binding validation error occurs, this event bubbles up in visual tree, so you can catch it easily for entire page, or usercontrol

You can use Validation.HasError and Validation.Errors attached properties to get binding errors. Also, became familiar with Validation.ErrorTemplate in case you aren't

Comment: Okay thanks. Will try it when I have the time and mark your answer if it works. Think I'll try the bubbling first, just need to find nice looking way to implement it.

Comment: basically, to disable the button, in your CanExecute method call `Validating` event. In your view, set `EventArgs.IsValid = Validation.GetHasError(this)`.